# Kali Linux is prompting me for the password to 'Default Keyring' but I never set one?

Tags: authentication

I am trying to login to a VPN on kali linux but when I try to connect using the VPN file I have, it prompts me to unlock my default keyring, but I never set the password for it. I am using Kali Linux on VirtualBox. [image: Here is an image of what I am talking about]

Answer (score 4):

Normally GNOME Keyring uses the same password as your OS login. Try that first. (Normally it also uses the OS password to automatically unlock the keyring, but if you've set up autologin or if you switched from graphical login to startx, this will no longer work.)

If the OS password doesn't work, destroy the keyring by removing all files from `~/.local/share/keyrings`, and *preferably* do a full reboot so that it'd initialize a new keyring in the same way that it normally does. You'll have to re-enter the VPN password after this, of course.

Comment: If anyone comes to this thread with the same problem, this was what solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

The keyring is personal for the user, and by default can't be modified without authentication to protect it. To unlock it simply enter your login password.